# Python Anaconda and azure-storage module

Tags: python, anaconda, azure-storage, azure-dsvm

I am using a Data Science virtual machine on Azure that has anaconda python installed.

I need to access module Azure storage blob using:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
```

When dealing with this command I receive the message that the module `azure.blob.storage` is not found. I have forced the update for the module `azure-storage`:

```
pip install azure-storage --upgrade
```

The missing module instead is present on the installed modules using:

```
pip freeze
```

After removing Anaconda and using the standard Python distro everything works well.

How can I continue using Anaconda with azurestorage support? Has anyone experimented this issue and solved it?

Comment: You need to make sure to use the version of pip associated with the Anaconda install. What is the output of `which pip`

Answer (score 2):

The Linux flavors of the Data Science Virtual Machine include two Anaconda environments: root, with Python 2.7, and py35, with Python 3.5. You should activate the one you want:

```
source activate py35
```

*pip* and *python* will then both refer to the same environment.

You may need to run *pip* as root to install packages. You can do with

```
sudo /anaconda/bin/pip
```

for the root environment, or

```
sudo /anaconda/envs/py35/bin/pip
```

for the py35 environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two installations for Python on Azure VM for Data Science, which include system level & Anaconda level.

As @darthbith said, it shows the path `/usr/local/bin/pip` when you run the command `which pip`, which is belong to system level.

You need to move to the path `bin` of Anaconda and install the modules you want using the `./pip` command for the current Anaconda, as below using jupyter terminal.

```
# For example, using anaconda for Python 2
nbuser@nbserver:~$ cd anaconda2_20/bin
# Using the Anaconda pip to install modules
nbuser@nbserver:~/anaconda2_20/bin$ ./pip install azure-storage --upgrade
# Then see the content below
Collecting azure-storage                                                                                                                  
  Downloading azure_storage-0.33.0-py2-none-any.whl (182kB)                                                                               
    100% |################################| 184kB 2.9MB/s                                                                                 
Collecting requests (from azure-storage)                                                                                                  
  Downloading requests-2.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (574kB)                                                                                
    100% |################################| 583kB 1.7MB/s                                                                                 
Requirement already up-to-date: azure-nspkg in /home/nbcommon/anaconda2_20/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from azure-storage)               
Requirement already up-to-date: azure-common in /home/nbcommon/anaconda2_20/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from azure-storage)              
Requirement already up-to-date: futures in /home/nbcommon/anaconda2_20/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from azure-storage)                   
Collecting cryptography (from azure-storage)                                                                                              
  Downloading cryptography-1.5.3.tar.gz (400kB)
.....
```

Then the `azure-storgae` module be upgraded for the current Anaconda.

Hope it helps.